# Working with strcmp and string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strcmp

I'm trying to eliminate extra elements in the string array and I wrote the code below. There seems a problem with strcmp function and string arrays. Strcmp doesn't accept the string array elements that way. Can you help me fix that? array3 is string array. I'm coding in C++ and What I want to do is like there are multiple "apple"s or "banana"s in the string array. But I only need one "apple" or one "banana".

```
for(int l = 0; l<9999; l++)
{
    for(int m=l+1;m<10000;m++)
        if(!strcmp(array3[l],array3[m]))
        {
            array3[m]=array3[m+1];
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by eliminating extra elements in string array ? array3 is of what type ? Also you should indicate which language .

Comment: There are more than one instance for each element in the string array. I mean more than one of the same string. I only need one of them

Comment: Can you explain "More than One instance of each element? Means If array has "AABCDD" so you want "ABCD"??

Comment: You are coding in C, not C++. C++ has a string class

Comment: `array3` appears to be one big c-string. Is that what you intended? If so, your code has no chance of achieving what you're asking - you're comparing on a character by character basis. There are much easier ways to this in C++ than using arrays and `strcmp`.

Comment: @Component10 No, if array3 was a single string, the strcmp wouldn't compile.

Comment: @MrLister: A fair point - helps if you read things carefully :) Stand by the second part though. `std::set` is your friend here. The `const char *`s can even be kept if the comparitor is customised.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` returns 0 on equality, so `if (strcmp(s1,s2))...` means "if the strings are equal then do this...". Is that what you mean?

Comment: So, You are expected to use (if(strcmp(s1,s2) == 0) in that case!

Comment: Sorry, typed that wrong. The integer value 0 in C/C++ evaluates as boolean `false`, so the test actually means "if not equal then..." so I think you need to negate your conditional.

Comment: yes but the Eclipse gives this error : - cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, 
  const char*)'
 - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int strcmp(const char *, const char *) '

Comment: Yes I saw that but still having problem with that Eclipse problem

Comment: For C++ std::string compare use string::compare.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use `operator==` to compare strings of `std::string` type:

```
std::string a = "asd";
std::string b = "asd";
if(a == b)
{
//do something
}
```

Second, you have an error in your code, provided 10000 is the size of the array:

```
array3[m]=array3[m+1];
```

In this line you are accessing the `m+1`st element, with `m` being up to 10000. This means you will eventually try to access the 10001st element, and get out of array bonds.

Finally, your approach is wrong, and this way will not let you remove all the duplicate strings. 
A better (but not the best) way to do it is this (pseudocode):

```
std::string array[];//initial array
std::string result[];//the array without duplicate elements
int resultSize = 0;//The number of unique elements.
bool isUnique = false;//A flag to indicate if the current element is unique.

for( int i = 0; i < array.size; i++ )
{ 
    isUnique = true;//we assume that the element is unique
    for( int j = 0; j < result.size; j++ ) 
    {
        if( array[i] == result[j] )
        {
            /*if the result array already contains such an element, it is, obviously, 
            not unique, and we have no interest in it.*/
            isUnique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //Now, if the isUnique flag is true, which means we didn't find a match in the result array,
    //we add the current element into the result array, and increase the count by one. 
    if( isUnique == true )
    {
        result[resultSize] = array[i];
        resultSize++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strcmp works on Cstrings only so if you wanna use it I suggest you alter it to the following: `strcmp(array3[l].c_str(),array3[m].c_str())` which makes the strings C Strings.

Another option would be to simply compare them with the equality operator `array3[l]==array3[m]` this would tell you if the strings are equal or not.

Another way to do what you're trying to do is just to put the array in a **set** and iterate over it. Sets don't take more than one string of the same content!

References:

- More about strcmp :http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp
- And moreabout c_str: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str
- Regarding String Comparison: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare
- C++ Sets http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set